# ld: library not found for -l-Xlinker

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm experiencing the following issue while trying to build / archive a React Native project:

> ld: library not found for -l-Xlinker

I'm posting this question as the error is a bit tricky and googling it won't help (hoping for this thread to show up for future search queries).

-Xlinker isn't a library but an argument of the clang command ran during the build.
Here's the relevant part of the faulty clang command line:

> [...] -lRNFetchBlob -lRCTImageResizer -l -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker [...]

As you can see, there's a `-l` alone here, which I guess is the cause of the error. I'm not very familiar with Xcode, but I went to check the "Link Binary With Libraries" part expecting there might be a empty line there, in vain.

Help or hints welcome!

`$ react-native --version
0.48.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked at the order the lib were called in the command line and noticed it was the same order as what appear in "Link Binary With Libraries". I indeed noticed that the last entry there was a "lib.a". I just removed it from "Link Binary With Libraries" and it solved the problem.